# Twitter GET Search returns empty result

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-search

I'm a little surprised the behavior of Twitter's search get method.

Few weeks ago i created twitter acount for testing. I used search get method to parse tweets, like this:

[http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=**netizencytest**](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=netizencytest)

It worked fine, but somewhere a week ago began returning empty result.

So, why it happened?
It still returns empty result for this account. Maybe.. twitter banned parse this account for some reasons?

Another accounts return result correctly, for example try this one [http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=**shymofficiel**](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=shymofficiel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link can help:
https://support.twitter.com/groups/32-something-s-not-working/topics/118-search/articles/66018-my-tweets-or-hashtags-are-missing-from-search-known-issue

Remember, twitter search only show recent tweets, and the last tweet from the account **netizencytest** is from Oct 16, try tweeting something new and try again.